# Compact range of data

Tags: javascript, statistics, curve

If I have this array:

```
[ 0.8, 2, 3.33, 60, 98.6 ]
```

What kind of function (in JavaScript) can I write to make the values closer together, but on a scale?  So that the smallest vals are still the smallest and the largest are still the largest, they are just closer?

Basically each of these vals is the radius of a bubble on a chart and I can barely see the small ones.. I want to make the small ones bigger and the big ones smaller proportionally.

Comment: Closer to what? To the minimum, maximum, or average?

Comment: I want to basically just make it so the range is less, but they are still on some sort of scale in relation to eachother

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make every value closer to the average.
Use a combination of [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```
var array = [ 0.8, 2, 3.33, 60, 98.6 ]
var average = array.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b
}) / array.length
var result = array.map(function (x) {
    return (x - average) / 2 + average
}) //=> [16.873, 17.473, 18.138, 46.473, 65.773 ]
```

Basically, this code calculates the average of your array, and then maps each value so that it is half the distance to that average.

Comment: I apologize, I guess I am not looking only to reduce the range - I have added more info to my question to clarify it further